# Why does TextFieldParser.ReadField remove consecutive newlines from middle of a field?

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, string, file-io

I am using VB.NET's TextFieldParser (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser) to read a delimited file.  However, when I try to read in a field with consecutive newlines within the field, the consecutive newlines are turned into a single new line.  I would like the consecutive newlines to be preserved, but am unsure how.

Here's an example file that I am reading in with exactly one field.  The quotes are part of the file's content and there are three newlines (including the two consecutive newlines following line 2):

```
"This is line 1
This is line 2

This is line 4, which follows two consecutive newlines."
```

Here is the code that I am using to parse and read in the file:

```
Dim reader as New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(myFile, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
reader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
reader.SetDelimiters(",")

Dim fields As String() = reader.ReadFields
Dim line As String = fields(0)
```

And here is the content of the "line" variable.  Note that there are only two newlines now:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 4, which follows two consecutive newlines.
```

What can I do to preserve the consecutive newlines?

Comment: I have the same problem, and have submitted a bug report to Microsoft here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/679596/textfieldparser-does-not-respect-consecutive-line-breaks-in-the-middle-of-a-field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, according to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readfields.aspx blank lines are ignored:

> If ReadFields encounters blank lines,
>   they are skipped and the next
>   non-blank line is returned.

I believe what you are going to need to do is use ReadLine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readline.aspx and then loop through the results.

```
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\ParserText.txt")
    MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    Dim currentRow As String
    While Not MyReader.EndOfData
        Try
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadLine()
            'Manipulate line...
        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")
        End Try
    End While
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe look at the "LineNumber" property?...

(c#)

```
var beforeRead = _parser.LineNumber;
_parser.ReadFields();
var afterRead = _parser.LineNumber;

if(afterRead <= -1)
   lineNumber = beforeRead;
else                    
   lineNumber = afterRead - 1;

for (var blankLines = beforeRead; blankLines < afterRead-1; blankLines++)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I've not tested all the edge cases of blank lines at the end etc tho.